# swift :changing the content of an array gives me an error

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift

I have this array :

```
var array = [[12,46,["a","b","c"],"nil",true,7,true],[10,40,["c","d","e"],"nil",true,7,true],[0,1,["z","l","w"],"hey",false,7,true]].
```

when I try to change the value of the last boolean of an array boolean by this code :

```
array[0][6] = false
```

I get this error "cannot assign through subscript subscript is get-only array"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting. I think the compiler tripped up somewhere. You only  have to examine the array's type to understand why:

```
var array = [
    [12,46,["a","b","c"],"nil",true,7,true],
    [10,40,["c","d","e"],"nil",true,7,true],
    [0,1,["z","l","w"],"hey",false,7,true]
]

print(array.dynamicType) // Array<NSArray>
                         // can't assign to the inner array since NSArray is immutable
```

Give Swift a hint of the inner type and it works

```
var array: [[AnyObject]] = [
    [12,46,["a","b","c"],"nil",true,7,true],
    [10,40,["c","d","e"],"nil",true,7,true],
    [0,1,["z","l","w"],"hey",false,7,true]
]

array[0][6] = false     // works
```

Comment: I wonder why the Swift compiler defaults to the non-Swift native type `NSArray`?

Answer (score 2):

You should use an array of tuples instead. Makes nicer code, performs better and no dependency on Objective-C:

```
var array = [
    (12,46,["a","b","c"],"nil",true,7,true),
    (10,40,["c","d","e"],"nil",true,7,true),
    (0,1,["z","l","w"],"hey",false,7,true)
]

// Array has type [(Int, Int, [String], String, Bool, Int, Bool)]

array[0].6 = false
```

Comment: This clarifies the programmer's intent, especially since all entries of the outer array have the same structure (`Int`, `Int`, `[String]`, `String`, `Bool`, `Int`, `Bool`).